# Rainbow scatter plot Python

Tags: python, scatter-plot

I have to make the following scatterplot in python. The code for this plot is :

```
n = 1024
X = np.random.normal(0,1,n)
Y = np.random.normal(0,1,n)

plt.scatter(X,Y)
```

[image: Scatterplot]

But as espected, this wont give the colours. I've tried a lot, but can't find the solution. I know it has something to do with the angle of X/Y in the plot, but can't find out how to do this.

Comment: What is the logic behind the coloring?

Comment: @alec_djinn It is from an exercise I have to do... Don't know the logic either, just have to find out on how to do this

Comment: So, are you asking how to use color gradients with scatter plots on maptplotlib or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic is most likely angle from origo to point. This can be calculated easily with `np.arctan2(X, Y)`. I don't know which colormap that is used in your example but you can probably find it here: https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html

Use the angles of the points to the `c` keyword in `plt.scatter`

To get something similar to your example:
`plt.scatter(X,Y, c=np.arctan2(X, Y), cmap='rainbow', s=50, alpha=0.8)`